# does "that this is impossible" mean "this is impossible that they were same individual"?

Tags: meaning

does "that this is impossible" mean "this is impossible that they were same individual"?

However, the student has certainly the right to claim that Florence Cook
and Katie King were the same individual until convincing evidence is
laid before him **that this is impossible**. Such evidence Professor Crookes
is very careful to give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. A more usual word order would be

> until convincing evidence that this is impossible is laid before him.

With the writer's word order, the sentence ends on the emphatic  "this is impossible".

Answer (score 0):

"This is impossible that they were same individual" is ungrammatical. To make it grammatical, you have to say:

- **It** is impossible that they were same individual.

In the sentence provided, the clause "that this is impossible" means "that it is impossible that they were the same individual".

Comment: Your answer is right; the OP's proposed substitution doesn't work and your correction would fix it. I missed that in my reply, focusing more on the meaning than on the substitution.